React Native: Tooltip Animated Text doesn't get updated, position works fine from same prop value
I am using VictoryNative to render area chart. Upon chart press I show a custom tooltip ChartPointsTooltip. This does change it's position based on the x value passed to it just fine, but the Current and Previous values derived from y and y2 never get updated and always show 0. Tried a bunch of different things but nothing worked

import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import {
    Circle,
    Line as SkiaLine,
    Text as SkiaText,
    Box,
} from "@shopify/react-native-skia";
import { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import {
    Dimensions,
    Text,
    TextProps,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View,
} from "react-native";
import {
    GestureHandlerRootView,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";
// biome-ignore lint/style/useImportType: <explanation>
import Animated, {
    SharedValue,
    useAnimatedProps,
    useAnimatedStyle,
    useDerivedValue,
    useSharedValue,
    withSpring,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import { Area, CartesianChart, useChartPressState } from "victory-native";

const DATA = Array.from({ length: 11 }, (_, i) => ({
    day: i,
    highTmp: 40 + 30 * Math.random(),
    highTmp2: 40 + 29 * Math.random(),
}));

// biome-ignore lint/suspicious/noExplicitAny: <explanation>
const FilterPill = ({ label, isActive, onPress }: any) => {
    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
            <View
                className={`px-5 py-1 rounded-full ${isActive ? "bg-ember-red-200 border border-ember-red-600" : ""}`}
            >
                <Text className="text-ember-red-600">{label}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
};

const AnimatedView = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(View);
const AnimatedText = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Text);

function ChartPointsTooltip({ x, y, y2, isActive }) {
    const TOOLTIP_WIDTH = 120; // Approximate width of tooltip
    const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
    const PADDING = 16; // Safe area padding from edges

    const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        // Calculate bounds-aware position
        let tooltipX = x.value - TOOLTIP_WIDTH / 2; // Center tooltip on touch point

        // Left bound
        tooltipX = Math.max(PADDING, tooltipX);

        // Right bound
        tooltipX = Math.min(SCREEN_WIDTH - TOOLTIP_WIDTH - PADDING, tooltipX);

        return {
            opacity: withSpring(isActive ? 1 : 0),
            transform: [
                {
                    translateX: withSpring(tooltipX),
                },
            ],
        };
    });

    // Create derived values using the correct structure
    const currentValue = useDerivedValue(() => {
        // y.value is the SharedValue containing the actual number
        return y.value.value.toFixed(2);
    });

    const previousValue = useDerivedValue(() => {
        // y2.value is the SharedValue containing the actual number
        return y2.value.value.toFixed(2);
    });

    const currentTextProps = useAnimatedProps(() => ({
        children: `Currentt: ${currentValue.value}`, // Remove .value since y is now the raw number
    }));

    const previousTextProps = useAnimatedProps(() => ({
        children: `Previouss: ${previousValue.value}`, // Remove .value since y2 is now the raw number
    }));

    return (
        <AnimatedView
            className="shadow-sm"
            style={[
                animatedStyle,
                {
                    top: 50,
                    position: "absolute",
                    zIndex: 20,
                    backgroundColor: "#f9cbb9",
                    padding: 16,
                    borderRadius: 12,
                },
            ]}
        >
            <AnimatedText
                animatedProps={currentTextProps}
                style={{
                    marginBottom: 8,
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    color: "#d64c1a",
                }}
            />

            <AnimatedText
                animatedProps={previousTextProps}
                style={{
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    color: "#009eac",
                }}
            />
        </AnimatedView>
    );
}

export default function SalesSummary() {
    const { state, isActive } = useChartPressState({
        x: 0,
        y: { highTmp: 0, highTmp2: 0 },
    });

    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView>
            <View className="bg-yellow-300 h-[65%] rounded-b-xl pt-12">
                <View className="p-4 flex-row justify-between">
                    <Text className="font-bold text-xl">Sales</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity className="h-8 w-8 shadow-sm items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-white">
                        <Ionicons size={20} name="time-outline" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <View className="p-4">
                    <Text className="font-bold text-xl">R 2135.20</Text>
                    <View className="flex-row items-center mt-1">
                        <Text>Gross Sale</Text>
                        <View className="bg-yellow-200 px-2 rounded-xl ml-2">
                            <Text className="text-xs text-red-500">R -42.3</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>

                    <View className="mt-4">
                        <View className="flex-row justify-between">
                            <View>
                                <Text className="font-bold text-xl">12</Text>
                                <View className="flex-row items-center mt-1">
                                    <Text>No. of Sales</Text>
                                    <View className="bg-yellow-200 px-2 rounded-xl ml-2">
                                        <Text className="text-xs text-red-500">R -42.3</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                            <View>
                                <Text className="font-bold text-xl">R 123.30</Text>
                                <View className="flex-row items-center mt-1">
                                    <Text>Avg. Sale</Text>
                                    <View className="bg-yellow-200 px-2 rounded-xl ml-2">
                                        <Text className="text-xs text-red-500">R -42.3</Text>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View className="mt-2 w-full flex-1 relative">
                    <View className="flex-row justify-around mt-4 mb-8 px-12">
                        <FilterPill label="1D" isActive />
                        <FilterPill label="1W" />
                        <FilterPill label="1M" />
                    </View>
                    <View className="flex-row items-center justify-center mb-4">
                        <View className="flex-row items-center">
                            <View className="rounded-full w-2 h-2 bg-ember-red-600" />
                            <Text className="text-xs font-bold text-ember-red-600 ml-1">
                                Current
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                        <View className="flex-row items-center ml-5">
                            <View className="rounded-full w-2 h-2 bg-[#009eac]" />
                            <Text className="text-xs font-bold text-[#009eac] ml-1">
                                Previous
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <ChartPointsTooltip
                        x={state.x.position}
                        y={state.y.highTmp}
                        y2={state.y.highTmp2}
                        isActive={isActive}
                    />
                    <CartesianChart
                        axisOptions={{ lineWidth: 0 }}
                        data={DATA}
                        xKey="day"
                        yKeys={["highTmp", "highTmp2"]}
                        frame={{ lineWidth: 0 }}
                        chartPressState={state}
                    >
                        {/*  render function exposes various data, such as points. */}
                        {({ points, chartBounds }) => {
                            //  and we'll use the Line component to render a line path.
                            return (
                                <>
                                    <Area
                                        connectMissingData
                                        curveType="natural"
                                        points={points.highTmp}
                                        color="#d64c1a"
                                        y0={chartBounds.bottom}
                                        opacity={0.75}
                                    />
                                    <Area
                                        y0={chartBounds.bottom}
                                        connectMissingData
                                        curveType="natural"
                                        points={points.highTmp2}
                                        color="#009eac"
                                        opacity={0.75}
                                    />
                                    {isActive && (
                                        <>
                                            <Circle
                                                cx={state.x.position}
                                                cy={state.y.highTmp.position}
                                                r={8}
                                                color="#d64c1a"
                                            />
                                            <Circle
                                                cx={state.x.position}
                                                cy={state.y.highTmp2.position}
                                                r={8}
                                                color="#009eac"
                                            />
                                        </>
                                    )}
                                </>
                            );
                        }}
                    </CartesianChart>
                </View>
            </View>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
}


